# Autocomplete jQuery não mostra opções

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

### **Descrição**

---

**Necessidade:** Preciso fazer um autocomplete com `jQuery`, `PHP` e a partir do que foi selecionado, pego o `ID`,  faço uma consulta no banco de dados e exibo o que preciso.

---

**Problema:** Não estou conseguindo exibir os registros no `input` que carrega o autocomplete. Observe o código abaixo de `Javascript`.

---

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$( "#consulta_estoque" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'js/autocomplete.php',
  select: function(event, ui){
      $( "#consulta_estoque" ).val(ui.item.descricaoProduto);
      alert(ui.item.codigoFabrica);
  }
});
```

---

**PHP**

---

```
foreach ($sql as $res) {
    $resultado[] = $res;
}
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

---

**JSON**

---

```
[
{
"codProduto":"9",
"codigoFabrica":"8019077",
"codSubcategoria":"0",
"descricaoProduto":"WWAKS3-5\/S366 CONECTOR M12 EUROFAST ANGULAR FEMEA",
"tipoItemEstoque":"0",
"c7flex":"9",
"ncmProduto":"85444200"
},{
"codProduto":"39",
"codigoFabrica":"8019078",
"codSubcategoria":"0",
"descricaoProduto":"WWAKS3-10\/S366 CONECTOR M12 EUROFAST ANGULAR MACHO",
"tipoItemEstoque":"0",
"c7flex":"39",
"ncmProduto":"0"
}
]
```

**Observação:** Acredito que o `JSON` está correto.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Pelo que vejo, seu JSON é um Array, por isso, não seria correto acessar: `ui.item[0].descricaoProduto` ao invés de `ui.item.descricaoProduto`? gostaria que você disponibilizasse o PHP inteiro para que eu possa incluir no http://jsfiddle.net para fazer um exemplo funcional

Comment: Então amigo, o php inteiro é complicado, pois são muitas classes para disponibilizar
Quanto ao json, acredito que esse é o formato correto

Comment: O problema é que não tenho como testar... então teste o seguinte para ver se funciona: `$( "#consulta_estoque" ).val(ui.item[0].descricaoProduto);` e `alert(ui.item[0].codigoFabrica);`

Comment: Abra o console do navegador (F12) e veja se você tem algum erro aparecendo.

Comment: O PHP parece estar correto, pois o JSON está certo. Pela [documentação do plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#source) a utilização também parece certa.

Comment: Pois e, e se eu fizer assim:
$resultado[] = $res['descricaoProduto'];
Mostra certinho, porém eu nao consigo pegar o id que foi clicado

Comment: Se fizer isso como fica o JSON?

Comment: ["WWAKS3-5\/S366 CONECTOR M12 EUROFAST ANGULAR FEMEA","WWAKS3-10\/S366 CONECTOR M12 EUROFAST ANGULAR MACHO"]

Comment: Obrigado pelo link da documentação @GustavoRodrigues foi muito útil para desenvolver a resposta.

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas atende sua dúvida?

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a documentação do plugin, são preciso 2 campos (deduzo que obrigatórios) no objecto JSON:

> An array of objects with ***label*** and ***value*** properties:
>   **Traduzido:** Uma array de objectos com propriedades ***label*** e ***value***

Assim, o seu JSON tem te ser alterado/completado para ser, por exemplo, assim:

```
var json = [{
    "label": "EUROFAST ANGULAR FEMEA",
        "value": "8019077",
        "codProduto": "9",
        "codigoFabrica": "8019077",
        "codSubcategoria": "0",
        "descricaoProduto": "WWAKS3-5\/S366 CONECTOR M12 EUROFAST ANGULAR FEMEA",
        "tipoItemEstoque": "0",
        "c7flex": "9",
        "ncmProduto": "85444200"
}, {
    "label": "EUROFAST ANGULAR MACHO",
        "value": "8019078",
        "codProduto": "39",
        "codigoFabrica": "8019078",
        "codSubcategoria": "0",
        "descricaoProduto": "WWAKS3-10\/S366 CONECTOR M12 EUROFAST ANGULAR MACHO",
        "tipoItemEstoque": "0",
        "c7flex": "39",
        "ncmProduto": "0"
}]
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82hdY/)

Em relação à parte do lado do servidor. Sugiro que o JSON seja passado via ajax. Ou antes do `autocomplete` ser agarrado ao `input` para o `source` já estar atribuído, ou então no `focus` do input:

```
$("#consulta_estoque").on('focus', function(){
    json = json.concat(json2); // aqui seria um pedido ajax
    $("#consulta_estoque").autocomplete({source: json});
});
```

Exemplo de versão usando ajax, chamádo quando o `focus` dispara:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'js/autocomplete.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (resposta) {
        var json = resposta;
        $("#consulta_estoque").autocomplete({source: json});
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle com ajax**](http://jsfiddle.net/nuQd5/) (usando o recente descoberto [jsontest.com](http://www.jsontest.com/))

Comment: eu não sabia deste site também http://jsontest.com muito bom!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o `source:` do jQuery Autocomplete UI necessita de um array de strings e não de um JSON, veja como ele seria funcional:

Primeiro você teria que colocar `descricaoProduto` em um array, e depois seta-lo como `source`:

```
$.getJSON('js/autocomplete.php').done(function (dados) {
  // Cria uma array adaptada ao plugin:
  var dadosAdaptados = $.map(dados, function (elemento) {
    return {
      label: elemento.descricaoProduto,
      value: elemento.codigoFabrica
    };
  });

  // Configura o autocomplete:
  $( "#consulta_estoque" ).autocomplete({
    source: dadosAdaptados,
    select: function (event, ui) {
      // Usa os dados conforme necessário:
      $( "#consulta_estoque" ).val(ui.item.label);
      alert('Código de fábrica:' + ui.item.value);
  }
});
```

Desta maneira ele funciona, por isso você tem que separar seu JSON em um array.

## [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqVpd/2/)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54249/discussion-on-answer-by-paulo-roberto-autocomplete-jquery-nao-mostra-opcoes)

Answer (score -2):

O link abaixo apresenta uma ótima solução para o que você está precisando:

```
http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/bootstrap-autocomplete
```

A solução apresentada utiliza a interface Bootstrap. Espero que ajude.